# mysqldb not installing

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi i am using python 2.7 working on windows 7. I have changed registry_key = SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.1 in site.cfg, and i apended the ld_args.append(‘/MANIFEST’) in msvc9compiler.py. But still i got this error please help what i have to do ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py", line 15, in 
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_ke
y'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: ok, i done that precompiled binaries how i can install MySqldb i don't know please help...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a precompiled binaries. You can get them  for example here :  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: ok, i installed precompiled binaries. It is stored site-packages. Now i am testing in python shell import it is not running. How can i work with it...

Comment: How can you use the precompiled binary using pip and inside a virtual environment?